# How to rewrite (not redirect) homepage only to a sub directory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website that has 2 wordpress installs.

```
/landing/* 
/blog/*
```

The actual webroot under / is basically empty.

I want the home page like http://www.example.com to serve the content under /landing/ I dont want it to redirect. I want the url in the browser to stay http://www.example.com if any links are clicked on that page they would just go to the normal page url like http://www.example.com/landing/somepage

Just the homepage needs to be re-written like this.

How do you do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DirectoryIndex directive

```
DirectoryIndex /landing
```

This will internally rewrite your homepage to /landing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DirectoryIndex

Comment: Please explain how they would use this, and what it does rather than just a comment.